# Modify compiled java class constructor access

Tags: java

i have a jar file with classes in it attached to my project but i cant instanciate object from those classes because the constructors are private and i cant change that because those files are in read only mode 
can someone help me in java  ?

```
private DicomImageViewer(String title,int w,int h) { 
} 

/**
 * @param   title
 */
private DicomImageViewer(String title) {
}
```

Comment: if they are `private` they are meant not to be used

Comment: You should use the `public` interface to do what you want with the class. If you don't know, look for some tutorials on the web...

Comment: what is the use of jar file full of classes if i cant instanciate any one of them ?

Comment: it's to use only the plublic interfaces and to provide just the specific functionalty. Though in Java you have weaving that can help you a little in tis direction (search also for AspectJ). But you should use the jar as for it is made to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we're talking about [DicomImageViewer of the PixelMed Project](https://github.com/venkmurthy/PixelMed-Fork/blob/master/com/pixelmed/display/DicomImageViewer.java)? Calling the constructors you provided wouldn't help much, because they do nothing. The only constructor that actually does something is `private DicomImageViewer(String title,String applicationPropertyFileName,String dicomFileName)` and is the one called by the main method.

So for this particular class you can simply call the main-method `DicomImageViewer.main(new String[]{filename})`. You will end up with the same functionality as you would get by calling the jar with `java -jar`, i.e. you don't get the actual instance of `DicomImageViewer`.

There is a way to call private constructors using reflection, though, but if above answer is already what you need, I can skip that part ;-) Doing this is never a good idea because these things are declared `private` for a reason. The author of said class is assuming that these constructors and methods can be changed without any notice and can be expected to regularly do so. So after an update of the jar, your whole application will break if private methods have vanished or changed their behavior.

Edit: You asked for it in the comments, so here it is ;-) Use it at your own risk.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class CallPrivateConstructor {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TargetClass tc = new TargetClass("value", 1, 2); // leads to compile error

        Constructor<TargetClass> c = TargetClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
        c.setAccessible(true);
        TargetClass tc = c.newInstance("value", Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2));
        System.out.println(tc);
    }

}

final class TargetClass {
    private String val;
    private int number1;
    private int number2;

    private TargetClass(String val, int number1, int number2) {
        this.val = val;
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "val: " + val + ", number1: " + number1 + ", number2: " + number2;
    }
}
```

As creator of a Jar you can prevent the call of `setAccessible` to succeed, so this solution might not work in your particular situation.

Comment: i may need the reflection part

Comment: @moxched Did my answer now help (or at least answered your question)?

Comment: yes it explains alot yet i'm still unable to benefit from the jar file

Comment: @moxched If I answered your question you might consider accepting it (that the using of private constructors didn't help you in the end, is not my fault ;-)